# Editing a file within a zipped file using JSZip

Tags: javascript, node.js, jszip

Using [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/), is there a way to edit a file within a zipped file?

I've tried looking for solutions and going through the API but I can't seem to find a solution.

Any help with this would be great! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can edit a file inside your zip with `.file` method.

```
zip.file("existing_filename", "new file content");
```

This method is used for adding and updating file content.

Just make sure the file already exist.

You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/file_data.html).

Comment: And the zip object can be created by loading from existing zip file with code like JsZip.loadAsync(fs.readFileSync('path/filename.zip'))

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the official [documentation](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/).

And here's a more complete Node.js example:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var JSZip = require("jszip");

async function zipDemo() {
    // read the existing zip file
    var zipData = fs.readFileSync("input.zip");
    var zip = await JSZip.loadAsync(zipData);
    // add a new JSON file to the zip
    zip.file("sample.json", JSON.stringify({demo:123}));
    // write out the updated zip
    zip.generateNodeStream({type:'nodebuffer', streamFiles:true})
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.zip'))
    .on('finish', function () {
        console.log("output`enter code here`.zip written.");
    });
}

zipDemo();
```