# Update Contents of Zip file without extracting (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip, jszip

## Situation

I have a local .zip file which contains many files and folders. Within this zip file, I want to update its contents without extracting/uncompromising.

Currently. I am able to do this with windows explorer by viewing the zip file and dragging/dropping a same-named file. Windows will then overwrite the file.

I am not sure if under the hood windows is extracting and re-zipping but it appears to be holding onto crucial information contained in the original zip compression that I need to retain.

I tried JSZip but it only appears that you can edit files you created with the library and not edit files that already exist.

## Question

Does anyone know how I can grammatically do what I manually did within windows explorer by dragging and dropping files in an open .zip file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Editing a file within a zipped file using JSZip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40773965/editing-a-file-within-a-zipped-file-using-jszip)

Comment: Kinda, I seem to have resolved my problem but not by using a local file. I am going to fine tune my solution and answer this question soon. Thank you very much for your help.